# RabbitMQ the consumer skipping the Received event and not getting the messages

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I have a simple rabbitMQ consumer but I believe that he is skipping the Received event.

When debugging line by line, it reads them, prints them and does all the logic that follows it.
but when I run it without debug, it doesn't.

I made sure there are messages in the queue:

[image]

Consumer Code:

```
namespace AutoMatcher.QueuesImpl
{
    public class RabbitMQImpl : IQueue
    {
        // 1. Message Received Event -- returns message
        // 2. private RabbitMq object implementation 
        // 3. under interfaces -- add new interfaces for queues that implements start listening and this event
        // 4. Installer object -- Registers private object as public interface in container
        private readonly IBotFactory _factory;
        public RabbitMQImpl(IBotFactory factory)
        {     
            _factory = factory;
        }
        public void StartListening()
        {  
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
            {
                HostName = "localhost",
                Port = 5672
            };
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

                    consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                    {
                        var body = ea.Body;
                        //await Task.Yield();
                        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                        Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
                        var jsonMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageWithoutUser>(message);
                        IBot bot = _factory.GetBot(jsonMessage);
                        bot.Execute(jsonMessage.MessageId, jsonMessage.UserId, jsonMessage.Likes, jsonMessage.Service, jsonMessage.Time);
                    };

                    channel.BasicConsume(queue: "messages",
                                         autoAck: true,
                                         consumer: consumer);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I really have no idea what's going on, any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: I think the problem you have is that your channel get disposed before you received a message. In debug mode you are slow enough to make it work.

Comment: Darem, post this I will approve this, I removed the using statement and closed  the channel myself as soon as it closes the connection and it worked...REALY WEIRED. how is it closing the channel before it is done, its even in their tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the following code section is problematic, because after leaving the using statement the connection is closed and therefore no message is ever received.

```
 using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
 {
      using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
      {
            ....    
      }
 }
```

Instead, you could save both the connection and the channel as properties.

```
public class RabbitMQImpl : IQueue
{
        private Connection _connection;
        private Channel _channel;

        private readonly IBotFactory _factory;

        public RabbitMQImpl(IBotFactory factory)
        {     
            _factory = factory;
        }

        public void StartListening()
        {  
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
            {
                HostName = "localhost",
                Port = 5672
            };
            _connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            _channel = connection.CreateModel();

            // your code

        }
}
```

You could implement the `IDisposable` interface in the class `RabbitMQImpl` to close the connection and the channel, but you should keep in mind that an "anti-pattern" can be created quickly, see this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452281/using-idisposable-to-unsubscribe-events#comment14320460_452321)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Invoking a manual dispose on channel after connection is closed solved it

Answer (score 0):

Call before class contrutor.

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
            {   HostName = "localhost",
                Port = 5672
            };
```

First create factory and then assign to _factory.

Comment: They are different factories, I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: there are two different factories, _factory is my class using the factory design pattern and the var factory is the connection factory which is declared in the body